# SQLITE update query fails

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite, qtsql

I am trying to update the table column by appending with new data of QtSQl database. I need to update the column `imgpath` by appending with new data.

Below is the code, but it always fails, what could be the issue?.

```
QSqlQuery query(db);
query.exec("create table table1 (id integer primary key autoincrement, time varchar(20), imgpath varchar(20))");

query.exec("insert into table1 values(NULL,'00:15:25','img0.jpg')");
query.exec("insert into table1 values(NULL,'00:15:25','img1.jpg')");

bool up = query.exec("update table1 set imgpath=concat(';newImage.jpg',imgpath) where ID=1");
if(up==false)
   qDebug()<<"Update failed";
```

**Update:**

*Complete code:*

```
     QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
     db.setDatabaseName("./newDB");
     db.open();

     QSqlQuery query(db);
     query.exec("create table table1 (id integer primary key autoincrement, time varchar(20), imgpath varchar(20))");

     query.exec("insert into table1 values(NULL,'00:15:25','img0.jpg')");
     query.exec("insert into table1 values(NULL,'00:15:25','img1.jpg')");




     //bool up = query.exec("update table1 set imgpath='newimage.jpg',time='' where ID=1");
     bool up = query.exec("update table1 set imgpath=concat(';newImage.jpg',imgpath)");
     if(up==false){
         qDebug()<<"Update failed";
         qDebug() << db.lastError();
     }

    query.exec("SELECT * FROM table1 limit 100");

     QVector<QStringList> lst;
     while (query.next())
     {
         QSqlRecord record = query.record();
         QStringList tmp;
         for(int i=0; i < record.count(); i++)
         {
             tmp << record.value(i).toString();
         }
         lst.append(tmp);
     }
     foreach (const QStringList &var, lst) {
         qDebug() << var;
     }
```

Comment: What is the error reported. Your queries look ok. I ran them on a test db and they are all correct.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment, the code `qDebug() << db.lastError();` giving me the output `QSqlError("", "", "")` seems no error printing.

Comment: The table is unchanged after the update? You have a record with id == 1?

Comment: Yes I have record with id=1, I will post the complete code.

Comment: Is this mysql or sqlite? Your code says `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE")`.

Comment: Sorry, You are correct, I was using `QSQLITE`, I will edit my question. But seems all the query I have used same as mysql from and it was working except the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support the concat function.  If you remove

```
imgpath=concat(';newImage.jpg',imgpath)");
```

and replace it with standard **colName='Value'** syntax I'm betting that everything will start working.  If you want to append text to the current value you should be able to do it with something like the following syntax:

```
bool up = query.exec("update table1 set imgpath=';newImage.jpg'||imgpath");
```